# Is there a way to change the style (font color) of a specific file entry in a JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

I'm currently working on a small app, and I have a list of files that are specific, and I have their abosolute path. I was wondering if there was a way to specifically target a file entry in a *JFileChooser* to change its font color (I'd guess with *setForeground*), and if there is a way to do so while changing directories (in a *Listener* callback I'd guess)

Here is the section of code where I generate the *JFileChooser* :

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV files", new String[] {"csv"});
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(dirname));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    Visualizer.loadCase(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that. You could take a look at the Java source responsible for rendering the dialog (which probably depends on the look-and-feel).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew it couldn't be this easy...I tried checking out the rendering of the JFileChooser, which goes to the JComponent renderer and then to the Container renderer. I don't think tinkering with renderer would work, I'd guess that all Components in the JFileChooser should have a background and foreground, the issue is locating the specific component so that it may be modified... If there's no way to do that, perhaps it is not possible :/

Comment: I saw that using a fileview it is possible to add an image to specific file entries, could this be a way to to that ?

Comment: Refer to the [Providing an Accessory Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory) section of _How to Use File Choosers_ from Oracle's Java tutorials.